# How to secure AWS credentials in frontend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a static website which is hosted in S3.
Now I need to upload a file to another S3 bucket via that frontend.
For that I am using AWS library.
Problem is I have to give the AWS access keys to the AWS library.
As hardcoding the credentials is a bad practice, what can I do to securely pass the access keys to the AWS library?

Answer (score 1):

Use AWS JavaScript SDK to call the sts:assumerole to get the temporary credentials that will be valid for certain time instead of hard-coding them in your code.
Once you get the Access key and secret key along with the SessionToken use them in AWS Library and the credential will be valid for 1 hour by default, if duration is not specified while calling assume role api.

Hope this helps